# Activerecord specifications with 2 different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to find a way to display all Vacancies from my Vacancy model except the ones that a user already applied for.
I keep the IDs of the vacancies a certain user applied for in a seperate model AppliedVacancies.

I was thinking something line the lines of:

```
@applied = AppliedVacancies.where(employee_id: current_employee)
@appliedvacancies_id = []
@applied.each do |appliedvacancy|
  @appliedvacancies_id << appliedvacancy.id
end
@notyetappliedvacancies = Vacancy.where("id != ?", @appliedvacancy_id)
```

But it does not seem to like getting an array of IDs. How would I go about fixing this?

I get following error:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 1: SELECT "vacancies".* FROM "vacancies" WHERE (id != 13,14)
                                                    ^
: SELECT "vacancies".* FROM "vacancies" WHERE (id != 13,14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely an SQL problem.

You cannot use `!=` to compare a value to a set of values. You need to use the `IN` operator.

```
@notyetappliedvacancies = Vacancy.where("id NOT IN (?)", @appliedvacancy_id)
```

As an aside, you can drastically improve the code you've written so far. You are needlessly instantiating complete ActiveRecord models for every record found in your `applied_vacancies` table, when all you need are the IDs.

A first pass at improvement would be to use `pluck` to skip the entire process and go straight to the list of IDs:

```
ids = AppliedVacancies.where(employee_id: current_employee).pluck(:id)
@notyetappliedvacancies = Vacancy.where("id NOT IN (?)", ids)
```

Next, you can go a step further and eliminate the first query all together (or rather, combine it with the last query as a sub-query) by leaving it as an AREL projection which can be subbed into the second query directly:

```
ids = AppliedVacancies.select(:id).where(employee_id: current_employee)
@notyetappliedvacancies = Vacancy.where("id NOT IN (?)",App)
```

This will generate a single query:

```
select * from vacancies where id not in (select id from applied_vacancies where employee_id = <value>)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a lot to learn to get my code efficient, as a beginner I'm mostly happy with "it works" but I know this is something I should really look out for. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Answer like @meagar, but Rails 4 way:

```
@notyetappliedvacancies = Vacancy.where.not(id: @appliedvacancy_id)
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a combination of both answers!